# Assigning legend in for-loop Matlab

Tags: matlab, for-loop, legend

I have tried giving the legend in the loop but it overwrites the previously written legend, how can insert them either in if statement or either in the for loop. Confused

```
    clear;
        vin=10
 for m=1:1:14;  

        vin=vin+10
    for i=1:1:27
        Wa_Ac = PVinv.CoreSizeModel();
        PVinv.CoreSelect(Wa_Ac,i);   
        loss_ind_core= PVinv.InductorLossModel(PVinv.m_L_Selected);

        if(i==1)
        p=plot(vin,loss_ind_core,'--gs');
        hold on
        end
        if(i==2)
        p=plot(vin,loss_ind_core,'--rs');
        end %...till i=27

        legend(obj.m_Core_List(i).name);
        xlim([10e3 90e3])
        set(gca,'XTickLabel',{'10';'20';'30';'40';'50';'60';'70';'80';'90'})
        grid on
        xlabel('Vin');
        ylabel('Power loss');
    end
 end
```

The called function

```
function obj = CoreSelect(obj, WaAc)
             obj.m_Core_Available= obj.m_Core_List(i);
            obj.m_L_Selected.m_Core = obj.m_Core_Available;

end
```

Comment: The answers below are correct to suggest moving the legend outside of your `for` loop. I would just add that you should move all of your plotting commands except `plot` outside of the loop. For example, you don't need to set the x-/y-labels on each iteration of the loop, just once at the end of the loop when you have plotted all your data.

Comment: Error:Cell array argument must be a cell array of strings.
Actually i has to loop 27 times for every m value.

Answer (score 10):

Create a cell array to hold the legend names.  Before the `for` loop define something like

```
legend_names = cell(1,27 * 14);
```

Then, during the loop fill the cell in:

```
legend_names{27*(m-1)+i} = obj.m_Core_List(i).name;
```

After the `end` set the legend:

```
legend(legend_names);
```

I might have misunderstood the indices (`m` vs `i`) and how they relate to the names, but the point is that you can pass a cell array to the legend function to create the legend at one time.

An example is:

```
>> legend_names=cell(1,2);
>> legend_names{1} = 'str';
>> legend_names{2} = 'str2';
>> plot(0:4,0:4)
>> hold on
>> plot(1:5,0:4)
>> legend(legend_names)
```

which would yield[image]

Comment: Error:Cell array argument must be a cell array of strings. Actually i has to loop 27 times for every m value. –

Comment: @Khalid - you can use a string matrix instead of a cell (see http://www.weizmann.ac.il/matlab/techdoc/ref/legend.html for legend documentation)

Comment: @Khalid where is the error coming in? I've edited it for 27 times for every m value

Comment: The error was at the point when legend command is executed. Legend was not accepting the cell characters as its arguments

Comment: @Khalid Make sure you are assigning strings to the cell.  It sounds like your cell array is not composed of strings.

Comment: For future reader: the example works perfectly for me in 2013b.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of collecting the legend string, you can just set the `DisplayName`-property in your plot commands. Also, you can collect the `linespec` arguments in a cell array to avoid code duplication, i.e.

```
linespec = {'--gs','--rs',... %# etc

(...) 

for i=1:1:27
        Wa_Ac = PVinv.CoreSizeModel();
        PVinv.CoreSelect(Wa_Ac,i);   
        loss_ind_core= PVinv.InductorLossModel(PVinv.m_L_Selected);


        p=plot(vin,loss_ind_core,linespec{i},'DisplayName',obj.m_Core_List(i).name);

end        

legend('show')
```

Comment: Used the logic but it turned out to be the same problem in the end, it rewrites on the previous legend values

Comment: It worked out, i was using the if statements to do it..But as I moved my ifelse statements outside the for loop things worked out

Answer (score 2):

When faced with this situation, each time through the loop I add the legend string to a cell array of strings, e.g.

```
legstr{i} = obj.m_Core_List(i).name;
```

and then display the legend once, after the end of the loop:

```
legend(legstr);
```